# imagePickerController : "Operation not permitted" in real device

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I am using imagePickerController to allow user to pick image to upload to firebase storage. The following code success on emulator but failed on real iphone device (the imagePickerController function is taken from the firebase sample here : https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/blob/master/storage/StorageExampleSwift/ViewController.swift)

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController,
                           didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion:nil)


    // if it's a photo from the library, not an image from the camera
    if #available(iOS 8.0, *), let referenceUrl = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as? URL {
        let assets = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withALAssetURLs: [referenceUrl], options: nil)
        let asset = assets.firstObject
        asset?.requestContentEditingInput(with: nil, completionHandler: { (contentEditingInput, info) in
            let imageFile = contentEditingInput?.fullSizeImageURL
            let filePath = "/\(Int(Date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate * 1000))/\(imageFile!.lastPathComponent)"
            // [START uploadimage]
            self.storageRef.child(filePath)
                .putFile(from: imageFile!, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
                    if let error = error {
                        print("Error uploading: \(error)")

                        return
                    }
                    self.uploadSuccess(metadata!, storagePath: filePath)
            }
            // [END uploadimage]
        })
    } else {
        guard let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage else { return }
        guard let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.8) else { return }

        let imagePath =
            //Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid +
        "/\(Int(Date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate * 1000)).jpg"
        let metadata = StorageMetadata()
        metadata.contentType = "image/jpeg"
        self.storageRef.child(imagePath).putData(imageData, metadata: metadata) { (metadata, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error uploading: \(error)")

                return
            }
            self.uploadSuccess(metadata!, storagePath: imagePath)
        }
    }
}
```

> 2017-11-03 19:52:08.274996+0800 tutorist[432:82569] [Generic] Creating an image format with an unknown type is an error
>   2017-11-03 19:52:09.315968+0800 tutorist[432:82569] Body file is unreachable: /var/mobile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0027.PNG
>
> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=257 "The file “IMG_0027.PNG” couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it." UserInfo={NSURL=file:///var/mobile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0027.PNG, NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0027.PNG, NSUnderlyingError=0x170852ab0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"}}
>   Error uploading: Error Domain=FIRStorageErrorDomain Code=-13000 "An unknown error occurred, please check the server response." UserInfo={bucket=tutorism-47c98.appspot.com, object=photo/531402728533/IMG_0027.PNG, NSURL=file:///var/mobile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0027.PNG, NSLocalizedDescription=An unknown error occurred, please check the server response., ResponseErrorDomain=NSCocoaErrorDomain, NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0027.PNG, NSUnderlyingError=0x170852ab0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"}, ResponseErrorCode=257}

Comment: You question is unclear. You said that are trying to upload a jpeg but the error only shows a PNG url